# Restrict two way binding before submit in angular2/typescript

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have **editPop up** where I edit the form field in pop up. Meanwhile a background form is displaying. In that form whatever I type in **editPop** is displaying in background form before submit. How can I prevent this before save function.

I need that to be displayed only after save not while editing in popUp.

I guess this is because of two way binding happening due to `c.cName`. How can I overcome this issue.

Please help.
I am here by sharing my HTML and TS code.

**HTML code**

```
 <md-card class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" *ngFor="let c of cL ">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      {{c.cName}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" style="text-align:right;padding-right: 0px;">
   <button class="iconBtn" (click)="openC(c)">
 <md-icon svgIcon="edit" style="color: rgba(0,0,0,0.54);height: 17px;width: 17px;"></md-icon></button>
   </div>
   </md-card>
```

**Edit button HTML**

```
<div class="modal-body row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                        <md-input-container style='width:100%'>
                            <input type="text" name="cName" mdInput [(ngModel)]="c.cName" placeholder="c" required>
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>
  </div>
```

**Save Button HTML**

```
<div layout-align="end center" layout="row">
<button md-raised-button class="md-raised color-white" (click)="newC(c)" [disabled]="!cForm.form.valid" style="width: 46%;margin: 10px 5px;">Save</button>
                    </div>
```

**Ts code:**

```
openC(c) {
 if(c) {
    this.msg = "edit";
    this.c = c;
    this.addC.show();
 } 
}
newC(c) {
  if(c._id) {    
    this.ApiService
         .editC(c,c._id)
         .subscribe(
           cs  => {
             this.toasterService.pop('success');
             this.addC.hide();
           },);
  } 
             this.ApiService
                 .getC()
                 .subscribe(
                   cs  => {
                     this.cs = cs.map(function(c) {
                        return {"value":c._id,"label":c.cName};
                      })
                     this.toasterService.pop('success');
                     this.cL = cs;
                    },
                   error => {
                     //console.log(error);
                   });
}
```

Comment: Please explain the part with 'it is taking entries in the div as well'. The this div don't have entry feature. Are you meaning you still can edit the other inputs underneath the popup ?

Comment: Please have a look question has been updated

Comment: Remove [(ngModel)] in the popup edit and manage the value with a variable. At the submit update the model with that value.

Comment: im new to this. Please help if i go wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to above answer you can do it like this

**IN HTML**

```
<md-input-container style='width:100%'>
   <input type="text" name="cName" 
    mdInput #updatedC [value]="c.cName"  placeholder="c" required>
 </md-input-container>
```

**IN TS**

```
update(updateC,c) {
c.cName:updateProject.value,
 this.ApiService
 .editc(C,c)
 .subscribe(
   c  => {
     this.toasterService.pop('success');
     this.editC.hide();
     this.ApiService
         .getC(this.c._id)
         .subscribe(
           c  =>{
             this.cL = c;
           },
           error => {
             //console.log(error);
           });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
<input type="text" name="cName" mdInput [(ngModel)]="c.cName" placeholder="c" required>
```

do:

```
<input type="text" #updated name="cName" mdInput [value]="c.cName" placeholder="c" required">
```

also change to:

```
<md-card class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" *ngFor="let c of cL; let i = index">
```

and

```
<button md-raised-button class="md-raised color-white" (click)="updateValue(i, updated.value)" [disabled]="!cForm.form.valid" style="width: 46%;margin: 10px 5px;">Save</button>
```

and in your component:

```
updateValue(id, newValue){
   this.cL[id].cName = newValue;
}
```

Hope this works!

Comment: ya i will try now

Comment: it is working but after i change value and click on submit its not getting updated with edited value

Comment: sorry not getting saved

Comment: i got this error : "Cannot set property 'name' of undefined"

Comment: ya it is in same html

Comment: for console.log(id+"and"+newValue); i got undefined and Artifu123 and the error "Cannot set property 'name' of undefined" i hope this is exception "this.cL[id].name = newValue;"

Comment: now got this error "Cannot set property 'cName' of undefined"

Comment: *ngFor="let c of cL | pfilter:filter" i actually have this so *ngFor="let c of cL | pfilter:filter ; let i = index" not taking i guess

Comment: i have no idea to do plunker

Comment: I am not sure but try this :     <button md-raised-button class="md-raised color-white" (click)="new(updated, i)" [disabled]="!cForm.form.valid" style="width: 46%;margin: 10px 5px;">Save</button> and in newC(c, id) and replace c._id reference with id

Comment: ya i will try, and tell you

Comment: hai, i am able to get in console what i had edit but not on page by using the answer which u had posted in answers

Comment: how to add let i="index", for this *ngFor="let c of cL | pfilter:filter "

Comment: ya that was wat i was looking for but, *ngFor="let c of cL | pfilter:filter; let i = index" but it is not taking

Comment: everything is fine, i am getting the new edited value in console as well, but i need to save that on page. I am not getting how to save. Please help

Comment: ya it is taking that line.. and i havent written anything na to save the new value in page.. do i need to write that newC(c) function in updateValue(id, newValue) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149242/discussion-between-vega-and-tulsi).